# How to detach between AVPlayerLayer from AVPlayer?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, avplayer, avplayerlayer

I am trying to play video in background.I did follow so many tutorial but I did not get appropriate results.For that I am using AVPlayer.The I follow this url through which I am able to play my video whenever application state is active.But I want to play music in background for that I need to detach AVPlayerLayer from AVPlayer.But whenever I want to access avPlayerLayer in background it is returning NULL.Please help me.

**This is my code:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
[self becomeFirstResponder];

[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setDelegate: self];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];

NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"sample"

                                     withExtension:@"m4v"

                                      subdirectory:nil];
avPlayerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:url];
self.songPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:avPlayerItem];


self.avPlayerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer: self.songPlayer];

self.avPlayerLayer.frame = self.view.layer.bounds;
UIView *newView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
[newView.layer addSublayer:avPlayerLayer];
[self.view addSubview:newView];

[ self.songPlayer play];


// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

iewController *vc=[[ViewController alloc]init];
NSLog(@"%@",vc.avPlayerLayer);
 vc.avPlayerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:nil];
 }



- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
 {
  ViewController *vc=[[ViewController alloc]init];
  vc.avPlayerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:vc.songPlayer];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a late answer but I hope an example from my own code is helpful (this code is in a custom UIView subclass; the view I am displaying my player in).

What is going on in a nutshell: I am grabbing the layer from the UIView object I have subclassed, I then force a cast to an AVPlayerLayer...and then from there it is as simple as using the built in methods.

```
- (void)removeLayerFromPlayer
{
    AVPlayerLayer *playerLayer = (AVPlayerLayer *)[self layer];
    [playerLayer setPlayer:nil];
}

- (void)reattachLayerToPlayer
{
    AVPlayerLayer *playerLayer = (AVPlayerLayer *)[self layer];
    [playerLayer setPlayer:**your AVPlayer object here**];
}
```

Typically the removeLayerFromPlayer method should be invoked from the AppDelegate in the applicationDidEnterBackground method. Use NSNotificationCenter (my suggestion).

reattachLayerToPlayer should be (probably) used when the user can see your app again. So invoke this from applicationWillEnterForeground...

NOTE: If your app is visible when the user double taps from the home screen, the player will NOT be attached to the layer at this time until the user selects your app. One possible workaround is to use a screenshot of the player as a placeholder prior to entering background.